# How can I use Go append with two []byte slices or arrays?

Tags: arrays, append, byte, go

I recently tried appending two byte array slices in Go and came across some odd errors. My code is:

```
one:=make([]byte, 2)
two:=make([]byte, 2)
one[0]=0x00
one[1]=0x01
two[0]=0x02
two[1]=0x03

log.Printf("%X", append(one[:], two[:]))

three:=[]byte{0, 1}
four:=[]byte{2, 3}

five:=append(three, four)
```

And the errors are:

```
cannot use four (type []uint8) as type uint8 in append
cannot use two[:] (type []uint8) as type uint8 in append
```

Which taken into consideration the alleged robustness of Go's slices shouldn't be a problem:

http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks

What am I doing wrong, and how should I go about appending two byte arrays?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Appending to and copying slices](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Appending_and_copying_slices)
>
> The variadic function `append` appends zero or more values `x` to `s` of
>   type `S`, which must be a slice type, and returns the resulting slice,
>   also of type `S`. The values `x` are passed to a parameter of type `...T`
>   where `T` is the element type of `S` and the respective parameter passing
>   rules apply.
>
> `append(s S, x ...T) S  // T is the element type of S`
>
> [Passing arguments to `...` parameters](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)
>
> If the final argument is assignable to a slice type `[]T`, it may be
>   passed unchanged as the value for a `...T` parameter if the argument is
>   followed by `...`.

---

You need to use `[]T...` for the final argument.

For your example, with the final argument slice type `[]byte`, the argument is followed by `...`,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    one := make([]byte, 2)
    two := make([]byte, 2)
    one[0] = 0x00
    one[1] = 0x01
    two[0] = 0x02
    two[1] = 0x03
    fmt.Println(append(one[:], two[:]...))

    three := []byte{0, 1}
    four := []byte{2, 3}
    five := append(three, four...)
    fmt.Println(five)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/2jjXDc8_SWT

Output:

```
[0 1 2 3]
[0 1 2 3]
```

Answer (score 10):

`append()` takes a slice of type `[]T`, and then a variable number of values of the type of the slice member `T`. In other words, if you pass a `[]uint8` as the slice to `append()` then it wants every subsequent argument to be a `uint8`.

The solution to this is to use the `slice...` syntax for passing a slice in place of a varargs argument. Your code should look like

```
log.Printf("%X", append(one[:], two[:]...))
```

and

```
five:=append(three, four...)
```