# How to add a struct to an array of structs in Go

Tags: arrays, go, struct

In golang I'm trying to make an array of messages, and the ability to easily add a new "object" to the array.

```
type Message struct {
    Name string
    Content string
}

var Messages = []Message{
    {
        Name: "Alice",
        Content: "Hello Universe",
    },{
        Name: "Bob",
        Content: "Hello World",
    },
}

func addMessage(m string) {
    var msg = new(Message)
    msg.Name = "Carol"
    msg.Content = m
    Messages = append(Messages, msg)
}
```

When building I get an error that says:

> cannot use msg (type *Message) as type Message in append

Why is `append()` not working (as I might expect from JavaScript's `array.concat()`), or is `new()` not working?

Any other tips on how to improve this code are welcome since I'm obviously new to Go.

Comment: See if adding ... after msg helps (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461462/how-can-i-use-go-append-with-two-byte-slices-or-arrays)

Answer (score 8):

Change these 3 lines

```
var msg = new(Message)
msg.Name = "Carol"
msg.Content = m
```

to

```
msg := Message{
    Name:    "Carol",
    Content: m,
}
```

and everything should work.  `new` creates a pointer to `Message`.  Your slice is not a slice of Message pointers, but a slice of Messages.

Answer (score 6):

In your code, `Messages` is a slice of `Message` type, and you are trying to append a pointer of `Message` type (`*Message`) to it.

You can fix your program by doing the following:

```
func addMessage(m string) {
    var msg = new(Message) // return a pointer to msg (type *msg)
    msg.Name = "Carol"
    msg.Content = m
    Messages = append(Messages, *msg) // use the value pointed by msg
}
```

Alternatively, you can declare `Messages` as a slice of `*Message`:

```
var Messages = []*Message{
    &Message{ // Now each entry must be an address to a Message struct
        Name: "Alice",
        Content: "Hello Universe",
    },
    &Message{
        Name: "Bob",
        Content: "Hello World",
    },
}
```

In above case, `addMessage` wouldn't require any changes. But you'll have to modify `Messages` access everywhere else.